What is the shortcut key for Mac Finder to achieve the same effect as PageUp/PageDown in Windows File Explorer when a file/folder is selected?
Option+Up/Down or Fn+Up/Down doesn't work. They scroll one screen up/down, but do not change the selected item to the first/last one in the next/previous screen.

Did you try Fn+[arrow key]? Source: https://osxdaily.com/2015/07/07/page-up-page-down-mac-keyboard/
